# Why won't my model display fully in a mod made with an older version of GameMaker?

Tags: game-maker

I have a model of a corkscrew that I am modding into a game made in what I *believe* was Game Maker 8.0. Unfortunately, there is little to indicate what version it was made in, other than that it was not GameMaker: Studio.

The problem with the model is that not all of it loads, and it just stops drawing. I made the model in GameMaker 8.0 Pro, through a simple 3D model-generating script that I wrote.

[image: This model is incomplete.]

I loaded this content into [Nintendo Nightmare](http://gamejolt.com/games/neen-ten-doo-nightmare/185160). I did these tests in the "Hyrule Field" level (room 11, in the game), as it has the widest open area. I used a completely blank save file, going in to this, and made no other relevant cheat codes. The code I used is below. In the mod, code input is through one-line format, but I have formatted them for readability. Why won't my model completely display?

**This code adds drawing capabilities to the mod objects.**

```
object_event_add(obj_stringe, ev_draw, 0, "execute_string(text2);"); 
global.corkscrew = d3d_model_create(); 
d3d_model_load(global.corkscrew, "Corkscrew.d3d"); 
global.spr_pipeTexture = sprite_add("pipeTexture.png", 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

**`text2` is a variable string executed every draw event of `obj_stringe`**

```
global.tube = instance_create(x, y, obj_stringe); 
global.tube.text2 = "tex=sprite_get_texture(global.spr_pipeTexture, 0); 
d3d_model_draw(corkscrew, x, y, z, tex);";
```

Comment: Your question gives the idea of showing sort of a screenshot to give us a hintt about your issue; however, all I can see is source code of a previous Game Maker version. What do you see when you execute your program? What's your Game Maker version? You need to include more info.

Comment: @liggiorgio I'm not actually running this in game maker. Read the post very carefully. This is a mod of a game maker game. The game itself accepts gml strings of code to be executed. I believe it was game maker 6 as that is what everything indicates to me (original release date, various extensions, etc.), but the program I am running it in is the one I linked. If there is a way to get the version number through code I can do that.

Comment: @liggiorgio is more info acceptable now?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The issue is that in older versions of game maker, models were stored in arrays which have a maximum storage of 32000 indexes, or roughly 10000 polygons. The newer versions (likely where the software you were viewing it in was made) don't have the same limit and don't store models in the same type of arrays. Therefore, models in older versions simply get "cut off" in memory and appear to stop drawing whereas newer versions of game maker lack such an issue.

Your only solution is to cut the model into smaller sub-models and draw each one individually (or just lower the polygon count).